# Why size of my object is not reduced?

Tags: c++, size, sizeof, reduce

I've written `CMyObject` class as follows:

```
class CMyObject 
{
public:

CMyOjbect(void) {};
virtual ~CMyOjbect(void) {};

public:
    ULONGLONG m_uField1;
    UINT m_uField2;
    BOOL m_bField3;
    int m_iField4;
    BOOL m_bField5;
}
```

To reduce the size of `CMyObject`, I changed it to:

```
class CMyObject 
{
public:

CMyOjbect(void) {};
virtual ~CMyOjbect(void) {};

public:
    ULONGLONG m_uField1;
    UINT m_uField2;

    short m_sField4;    // Change from int to short, since short is enough for the data range

    unsigned m_bField3: 1;      // Change field 3 and 5 from BOOL to bit field to save spaces
    unsigned m_bField5: 1;
}
```

However, the `sizeof(CMyObject)` is still not changed, why?

Can I use `pargma pack(1)` in a `class` to pack all the member variables, like this:

```
pargma pack(1)

class CMyObject 
{
public:

CMyOjbect(void) {};
virtual ~CMyOjbect(void) {};

public:
    ULONGLONG m_uField1;
    UINT m_uField2;

    short m_sField4;    // Change from int to short, since short is enough for the data range

    unsigned m_bField3: 1;      // Change field 3 and 5 from BOOL to bit field to save spaces
    unsigned m_bField5: 1;
}

pargma pack(0)
```

Comment: "can I...."   well, did you try it?

Comment: Depends on the compiler, which are you using? However, you've also added a virtual function to the object, which will add RTTI and a v-table to the class, so just making the destruct-or non-virtual would make the class significantly smaller.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, the object itself only contains a *pointer* to the vtable, so no matter how many virtual functions you have it only adds the size of a pointer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but if hes trying to sheer off the bytes, 1 pointer (8 bytes on 64 bit systems) is pretty big. But more importantly, it also adds the RTTI for the class, which is a compiler specific size but probably also atleast a pointer (8 bytes).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I always assumed RTTI just added some stuff to the vtable itself so it wouldn't have any affect on object size.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: RTTI is stored as part of the vtable, i.e. in a typical implementation it does not affect object size more than the first virtual function does.

Answer (score 4):

Because of your `ULONGLONG` first member, your structure will have 8-byte (64-bit) alignment.  Assuming 32-bit ints, your first version uses 18 bytes, which would take 24 bytes to store.  (The large and small members are interspersed, which makes the matter worse, but by my count, that doesn't change the answer here.)  Your second version also takes 18 bytes:

- 8 bytes for `m_uField1`
- 4 bytes for `m_uField2`
- 2 bytes for `m_sField4`
- 4 bytes for the two `unsigned` bitfields (which will have 4-byte alignment, so will also inject 2 bytes of padding after `m_sField4`)

If you switch to `short unsigned m_bField3:1` and `short unsigned m_bField4:1`, I think there's a good chance your structure will become smaller and fit in only 16 bytes.

Use of `#pragma pack` is not portable, so I can't comment on the specifics there, but it's possible that could shrink the size of your structure.  I'm guessing it may not, though, since it's usually better at compensating for nonoptimal ordering of members with alignment, and by my counts, your variables themselves are just too big.  (However, removing the alignment requirement on the `ULONGLONG` may shrink your structure size in either version, and `#pragma pack` may do that.)

As @slater mentions, in order to decrease the size and padding in your structure, you should declare your member variables of similar sizes next to each other.  It's a pretty good rule of thumb to declare your variables in decreasing size order, which will tend to minimize padding and leverage coinciding alignment requirements.

However, the size of the structure isn't always the most important concern.  Members are initialized in declaration order in the constructor, and for some classes, this matters, so you should take that into account.  Additionally, if your structure spans multiple cache lines and will be used concurrently by multiple threads, you should ideally put variables that are used together nearby and in the same cache line and variables that are not used together in separate cache lines to reduce/eliminate false sharing.

Comment: _' It's a pretty good rule of thumb to declare your variables in **decreasing** size order'_ I read @slater's answer just vice versa (which makes sense BTW)??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, either should do the trick.  The important thing is that same-sized, same-aligned variables are near each other and near the variables with the next-larger alignment so they can slip into the end-gaps of each other's padding.  What's most important is consistency.

Comment: _'same-aligned variables are near each other and near the variables  ...'_ I see, that makes sense yes!

Comment: @Adam H. Peterson: You are forgetting about VMT pointer, which will occupy 4 or 8 more bytes (and the alignment will probably make it contribute 8 in all cases), which is why there's no way this can fit in 16 bytes. The minimal size will be 24 bytes. Changing the bit-field type to `unsigned char` or `unsigned short` should do the trick.

Comment: @AndreyT Yeah, I didn't catch the virtual function when I originally read the question.  I usually assume that if someone is micromanaging the size of their objects or considering `#pragma pack`, they're not using polymorphism (which was an incorrect assumption in this case).  But other than the invisible vptr (which adds a pointer and sometimes padding, depending on 32- or 64-bit pointers), I believe the rest of the analysis is essentially correct.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your first question "However, the `sizeof(CMyObject)` is still not changed, why?"

Your `BOOL`s are not defined contiguously, so they are padded by the compiler for the purposes of memory-alignment.

On most 32-bit systems, this struct uses 16 bytes:

```
struct {
  char b1; // 1 byte for char, 3 for padding
  int i1;  // 4 bytes
  char b2; // 1 byte for char, 3 for padding
  int i2;  // 4 bytes
}
```

This struct uses 12 bytes:

```
struct {
  char b1; // 1 byte
  char b2; // 1 byte, 2  bytes for padding
  int i1;  // 4 bytes
  int i2;  // 4 bytes
}
```

Comment: It is best to put the answer directly in SO, so that you don't need to worry about dead links.

Comment: If `BOOL` is the one used by Microsoft, it's the same size as `int`. I would expect replacing it with a bitfield to cut it in half.

Comment: @slater, I think you may have a cut-and-paste OBO error.  The `char` members will result in 3 bytes of padding each, not 2.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson fixed. Believe it or not I typed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment and packing are implementation dependent, but typically you can request smaller alignment and better packing by using smaller types. That applies to specifying smaller types in bit-field declarations as well, since many compilers interpret the bit-field type as a request for allocation unit of that size specifically and alignment requirement of that type specifically.

In your case one obvious mistake is using `unsigned` for bit fields. Use `unsigned char` for bit fields and it should pack much better

```
class CMyObject 
{
public:

CMyOjbect(void) {};
virtual ~CMyOjbect(void) {};

public:
    ULONGLONG m_uField1;
    UINT m_uField2;

    short m_sField4;

    unsigned char m_bField3: 1;
    unsigned char m_bField5: 1;
};
```

This will not necessarily make it as compact as `#pragma pack(1)` can make it, but it will take it much closer to it.

Comment: Thanks. I think 

unsigned m_bField3: 1; 

will also take 1 bit in the space? What is the difference between"unsigned m_bField3: 1;" and "unsigned char m_bField3: 1;"?

Comment: @user2704265: No, that's not how it works. In a typical implementation `unsigned m_bField3: 1` will *allocate* the entire `unsigned` unit of memory and then *use* 1 bit of that memory, leaving the rest unused. Similarly, `unsigned char m_bField3: 1` will allocate `unsigned char` of memory and use one bit of it. In your original code, you allocate the entire `unsigned` and then use 2 consecutive bits of it. That is very wasteful and that is why the end result is too large. Using `unsigned char` in this context will reduce it significantly.

Comment: For example, in VS 2012 compiler this change reduces the total size of `CMyObject` from 32 to 24. Judging by the code, this is the compiler family you've been using (most likely), and 32 is probably what you were getting as `sizeof`. As you can see, a mere change to `unsigned char` in bit-fields reduces the size to 24.

Comment: Is it possible to allocate both m_bField3 and m_bField5 in a single unsigned char instead of using two? To save a unused char? Since I may also need to add an additional BYTE field at the end of the object.

Comment: @user2704265: It *is* allocated in a single `unsigned char`! When you declare several consecutive bit-fields *of the same type* they are allocated in the same memory unit (in the same `unsigned char` in this case) as long as there is room there. The reason you get 24 as the size with `unsigned char` is *padding* added for alignment purposes at the end of the class. This padding cannot be eliminated unless you force it with `#pragma pack(1)`. With `#pragma pack(1)` you will be able to reduce the size to 23 in 64-bit builds and to 19 in 32-bit builds.

Comment: It is for you to decide whether `#pragma pack(1)` is worth it. It will save some memory, but might reduce performance.